# using canon 5D markiii or Olympus OMD EM5 as computer video camera?

Tags: video-capture

I tried the EOS utility and cam link USBs but nothing works for the two cameras that I own---canon 5D mark iii or Olympus OMD EM5. I understand that they are pretty old models. I was wondering if anyone figured out how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these cameras offers video out. They are still cameras that can take limited movies, that you can then download using the USB port for bulk transfer.

It's really worth reading the manuals for your cameras - if you don't have them with your camera, they are available for free online.

Answer (score 1):

5D Mark III... I  believe has uncompressed hdmi out. You need usb 3 on your PC and a device like a Magwell HDMI to USB or Logitech Screen Share. Or a Black Magic Design mini Recorder PCIe card. The Magwell is a nice piece of gear. I disagree with "limited movies" with respect. My Canon DSLR takes 1080p@24 @30 720p@60 video. But the original poster wants to use a DSLR as a studio camera or high quality "webcam" I believe.

Update: If you are on a Linux host this guy has a solution for you.
gphoto2 vl2loopback and ffmpeg into OBS.

I never tried this one... Canon Web Cam Utility. It is new.
https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/self-help-center/eos-webcam-utility/

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to achieve this with a Canon, is to use the EOS utility to display the video on your monitor, then use a screen-capture app like CamTwist, to capture an area of your screen and turn it into a virtual camera. Not idea, as anything accidentally straying into that part of the screen will appear in your webcam output.